# ListBox instead of ItemsPresenter in WPF Custom Control?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, generics, controltemplate

I'm writing a **generic control template** for my WPF Custom Control.
But with `ItemsPresenter` I only got raw list of Data.. 
Compared to the ListBox, the ListBox has all features I need.

Is it wrong to use a `ListBox` instead of `ItemsPresenter` ?

What I'm after is that 
if I write a generic Template that uses a `ListBox` and in code behind I register some `ListBox` specific events and somebody overrides my generic `Template` with his own `ControlTemplate` witn an `ItemsControl` inside that does not possess that event, it will raise an Exception. In case of `ItemsPresenter`, everyone could use what he wants to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could add some test to see if the ItemsControl in the template is a ListBox or not. For example:

```
var itemsControl = this.Template.FindName("PART_Items", this);
if(itemsControl is ListBox)
{
  // wire additional event handler here
}
```